# Document found on table but not present on an global secondary index

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

really wondering what's going on here.

We have stored documents in the (abreviated) form:

```
{
  "a_certain_id": "259217078123",
  "name": "company name",
  "vat_number": "BE0912111111"
}
```

the pk in the table is the "vat_number" property, but we also have a global secondary index on "a_certain_id".

When we perform a **query** on the table with the vat number, we get the document as expected.

We then perform a **query** on the secondary index with the copy-pasted property from the document,
and we find no document.

We then perform a **scan** with the vat number described above, no document is found.

I can only conclude that the document doesn't exist in the index!

Is there a way to manage this, such as repopulating the index or is there something wrong with the chosen hash key / pk? It shouldn't acccording to the documentation.

We do the queries in the following form:

```
key_condition_expression = Key(hash_key).eq(hash_value)
query_args = {"IndexName": index, "KeyConditionExpression": key_condition_expression}

result = dynamo_table.query(**query_args)
```

but that should not matter as we get the same result either via boto3 or via the aws console client.

And the query is working for most companies, it's only companies which are not in the index, apparently.

Comment: How are you doing your queries/scans (i.e. are you using an SDK, if so, what language)? Can you give some sample code?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I've edited the message with sample code but we have the same issue using aws dynamodb console client or boto3. And the code works for the majority of the companies, it's just a fraction which are not found in the index.

Comment: "the query is working for most companies" suggests that either a) the data for the one you think you are querying isn't as you think it is, or b) there is something wrong. If you are certain it's "b" then I would open a support ticket with AWS.